# Programmatically get hierarchy depth of a Simulink model considering subsystems and referenced models

Tags: matlab, simulink

I can get the hierarchy depth of a model using [subsystem depth metric](https://www.mathworks.com/help/slvnv/ref/model-metric-checks.html#buuybtl-1) from the Verification and Validation toolbox, but this metric does not follow (i.e. count) the referenced models.

> Depth traversal analysis stops when it reaches a referenced model or a
>   library.  Depth and level is restarted with 0 for each of these
>   components.

I do not understand why this metric has this behavior. Why doesn't it count the depth following the referenced models?

In order to achieve this (calculate hierarchy depth following both subsystem and referenced models) the most efficient way, can I create a [custom metric](http://www.mathworks.com/help/slvnv/ug/create-model-metrics-by-using-apis.html) extending the `subsystem depth metric`? In this case, I'll have to locate code for the subsystem depth metric; I don't know where to get this code. Or are there any existing programmatic API to get the metric I'm interested in?

Note: Originally posted in Matlab Answers site, but cross-posting here since I did not get any answers there.

Comment: Why would you want to continue counting inside libraries or referenced models? The typical use of the depth metric is to ensure that a model has been broken up in to seperate reference models/libraries so that a single model file does not contain 'too much' complexity.

Comment: In general, I want to view how models are organized hierarchically, and both Referenced Models and Subsystems can be used to hierarchically design a model. Too avoid "too much" complexity, the model can organize it's functionalities using both subsystems and referenced models, in my understanding.